# iOS event handling in complex applications

Tags: ios, event-handling

I've been developing for Android for quite a while, and now started learning iOS, and here's the thing:

On Android, when you have a massive amount of events going through the application, it becomes very tedious creating and implementing all these interfaces (protocols), subscribing and unsubscribing and stuff. And there's a couple of very good eventbusses, for example an Otto by Square https://github.com/square/otto

So I was wondering, is there any standart solution for iOS to handle various events across various application elements, or it's done by implementing and subscribing protocols, too? Or maybe there's some cool eventbus library for it, like on Android?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, `NSNotificationCenter` serves that basic purpose for application-specific events.  (As opposed to low-level events.)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you are asking. Of course, my apps don't tend to have a "massive amount of events" running. For most apps you simply use actions and a some methods. However, for games and some more advanced applications, I would see that you would need more ongoing events.

Comment: @PhillipMills that's exactly what I needed, thank you a lot! can you make your comment as an answer, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Or, you can try Tolo, an Otto inspired, equally easy to use and powerful, event publishing framework for iOS. Simply `SUBSCRIBE()`, or `PUBLISH()` from anywhere.

Check it out at http://genzeb.github.io/tolo

Answer (score 6):

`NSNotificationCenter` serves as a built-in distribution mechanism for application-specific events. (As opposed to low-level events.)